# Enabling Integrated Graphics card and Nvidia Graphics card

Tags: linux

I have IGC (intel) and Nvidia graphics card.
currently my progress bar during boot time displays on the monitor connected to IGC (intel) .

requirement : Progress Bar during Boot time should display in the monitor connected to Nvidia.

Bios setting: 
      `Primary Display : PEG (other options :auto/IGFX/PCI/SG)
      Primary PEG : Auto (other options :PEG11,PEG12,PEG60)
      Internal Graphics: Enable. (other options :Auto,Disable)`

/boot/grub/grub.conf:
`default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title HELiOS (2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=912ea1fe-12e3-4ed1-bae6-4d59bc3c60c0 nomodeset rd_NO_LUKS  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_NO_LVM rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet i915.modeset=1
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64.img`

my xorg.conf  for nvidia:
`Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
        Option                  "NoLogo"
EndSection`

my xorg1.conf :

`Section "Device"
               Identifier "Card0"
        Driver     "intel"
        BusID      "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
Section "Module"
        Load  "glx"
EndSection`

NVIIDA Graphics CARD : 
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GL [Quadro 410] [10de:0fff] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Kernel version :
2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Any luck with getting this setup to work?

Comment: This is a bit distro specific and I assume you are using a laptop right? Take a look on this:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-set-up-prime-with-nvidia-proprietary-driver/40225